# Should ReactJS be used in conjunction with an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

If I were to use ReactJS to build a website, should I add the javascript source code to an existing HTML file or should I just write it all and render it in the javascript file? How do most developers go about using React? Are .html files ever used during development or is it all done using .js files? Sorry for the basic question, I am just trying to figure out the best way to use React. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on how you create your project you can either have 0, 1, or more than 1 html files - this will depend on how manually you create the project (see the bottom of this answer for more context regarding create react app). most projects have 99% of the code as .js/.jsx files. most projects also use webpack to bundle the code into 1 final js file but that's not a requirement, you can just load react and your code each into a `<script />` tag in your html file.

99% of the time react will generate the html for you. there are instances where you want to inject pre-written html but that's a different topic and a small use case.

another use case where you may need multiple html files is if you have different application entry points, but it all really depends on what you're doing and the structure of your project, there's always more than 1 way to do this.

as @Mellet points out, you can also use Create React App, which allows you to not have to even create the html file. again, it all depends on your needs and wants

Comment: Take a look at [Create React app](https://create-react-app.dev/). It fixes the 1 html file and the bundling for you. So you just need to write the react code.

Comment: Thank you this is super helpful! So just one more follow up question: if I use react and do pretty much all my work in a .js file, I am assuming I wouldn’t be able to also work within a framework such as bootstrap. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jerry you should be able to use bootstrap, whether its just the css library or if you use the bootstrap react components. you can also use material ui react components or others like ant design. just install the npm package or load in the library via script tags and you should be able to use them with your own code